# Is it possible to convince clang to auto-vectorize this code without using intrinsics?

Tags: vectorization, simd, llvm-clang, micro-optimization, avx2

Imagine I have this naive function to detect sphere overlap. The point of this question is not really to discuss the best way to do hit testing on spheres, so this is just for illustration.

```cpp
inline bool sphere_hit(float x1, float y1, float z1, float r1,
        float x2, float y2, float z2, float r2) {
    float xd = (x1 - x2);
    float yd = (y1 - y2);
    float zd = (z1 - z2);

    float max_dist = (r1 + r2);

    return xd * xd + yd * yd + zd * zd < max_dist * max_dist;
}
```

And I call it in a nested loop, as follows:

```cpp
std::vector<float> xs, ys, zs, rs;
int n_spheres;
// <snip>
int n_hits = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n_spheres; ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < n_spheres; ++j) {
        if (sphere_hit(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i], rs[i],
                xs[j], ys[j], zs[j], rs[j])) {
            ++n_hits;
        }
    }
}
std::printf("total hits: %d\n", n_hits);
```

Now, clang (with `-O3 -march=native`) is smart enough to figure out how to vectorize (and unroll) this loop into 256-bit avx2 instructions. Awesome!

However, if I do anything more complicated than increment the number of hits, for example calling some arbitrary function `handle_hit(i, j)`, clang instead emits a naive scalar version.

Hits should be very rare, so what I think should happen is checking on every vectorized loop iteration if the value is true for *any* of the lanes, and jumping to some scalar slow path if so. This should be possible with `vcmpltps` followed by `vmovmskps`. However, I can't get clang to emit this code, even if I surround the call to `sphere_hit` with `__builtin_expect(..., 0)`.

Comment: _Maybe_ writing another inner-loop into your current inner loop which first writes the result of 8 `sphere_hit` calls into a bit-set (and hope that this generates a `movemask` instruction) could work. (If the bitset is non-zero, loop through the bitset).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is possible to convince clang to vectorize this code. With compiler options
`-Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize`, clang claims that the floating point operations are vectorized, which is confirmed by the [Godbolt output](https://godbolt.org/z/CrNMYL). (The red underlined `for`s are not errors, but vectorization reports).

Vectorization is possible by storing the results of `sphere_hit` as chars to a temporary array `hitx8`.
Afterwards, 8 `sphere_hit` results are tested per iteration by reading the 8 chars back from memory as one `uint64_t a`. This should be quite efficient since the condition `a!=0` 
(see code below) is still rare since sphere hits are very rare. Moreover, array `hitx8` is likely in L1 or L2 cache most of the time.

I didn't test the code for correctness, but at least the auto-vectorization idea should work.

```c
/* clang -Ofast -Wall -march=broadwell -Rpass-analysis=loop-vectorize -Rpass=loop-vectorize -Rpass-missed=loop-vectorize */
#include<string.h>
char sphere_hit(float x1, float y1, float z1, float r1,
        float x2, float y2, float z2, float r2);
void handle_hit(int i, int j);

void vectorized_code(float* __restrict xs, float* __restrict ys, float* __restrict zs, float* __restrict rs, char* __restrict hitx8, int n_spheres){
    unsigned long long int a;
    for (int i = 0; i < n_spheres; ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n_spheres; ++j){
            /* Store the boolean results temporarily in char array hitx8.     */
            /* The indices of hitx8 are shifted by i+1, so the loop           */
            /* starts with hitx8[0]                                           */
            /* char array hitx8 should have n_spheres + 8 elements            */
            hitx8[j-i-1] = sphere_hit(xs[i], ys[i], zs[i], rs[i],
                    xs[j], ys[j], zs[j], rs[j]);
        }
        for (int j = n_spheres; j < n_spheres+8; ++j){
            /* Add 8 extra zeros at the end of hitx8.                   */
            hitx8[j-i-1] = 0;     /* hitx8 is 8 elements longer than xs */
        }
        for (int j = i + 1; j < n_spheres; j=j+8){
            memcpy(&a,&hitx8[j-i-1],8);
            /* Check 8 sphere hits in parallel:                                   */
            /* one `unsigned long long int a` contains 8 boolean values here      */ 
            /* The condition a!=0 is still rare since sphere hits are very rare.  */
            if (a!=0ull){ 
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+0] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+0);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+1] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+1);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+2] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+2);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+3] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+3);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+4] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+4);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+5] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+5);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+6] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+6);
                if (hitx8[j-i-1+7] != 0) handle_hit(i,j+7);
            }
        }
    }
}


inline char sphere_hit(float x1, float y1, float z1, float r1,
        float x2, float y2, float z2, float r2) {
    float xd = (x1 - x2);
    float yd = (y1 - y2);
    float zd = (z1 - z2);

    float max_dist = (r1 + r2);

    return xd * xd + yd * yd + zd * zd < max_dist * max_dist;
}
```

Comment: Very clever answer.

Comment: Not as good as manual vectorization, but yeah there's enough SUB/FMA work to hide the throughput cost of the 3 shuffles with extract / `vpackssdw` / `vpackuswb`.  The hit-position detection is a lot less efficient than `vpmovmskb` / `bsf` though.  Still, better than nothing if you need it to be portable.

Comment: @PeterCordes: In principle it is possible to replace the 8 `if`s for the hit detection by a short loop of size  `popcount(a)` with a `bsf`, and an `a=a&(a-1)` to reset the lowest set bit (or BMI1 `blsr` instruction), each step. That would have been a bit more efficient probably, but with a rare `a!=0`, I wouldn't expect a huge performance benefit.

Comment: Right, I should have said the hit *checking* is less efficient than `vpmovmskb / test eax,eax` interleaved with the SIMD work.  The code for `a!=0ull` is part of a loop that jumps forward inside the loop, and has more loop overhead than you'd like for simply checking an array that you expect to be all-zero.  I'd be worried about uop-cache throughput for an effectively tiny loop body split into 2 parts, especially on Intel CPUs where the LSD is disabled by microcode updates.  And 2 taken branches is not good.  Probably an `UNLIKELY()` macro could help there, or profile-guided optimization.

Comment: Probably it's basically fine and only a bit slower than ideal vectorization if it has a core to itself, but less hyperthreading-friendly with the extra uops for shuffling.